# javascript countdown reset on each page load?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm completely lost with this bit of javascript (view source): http://www.fff2012.com

and the following php that opens up the page:

It is for a countdown timer that needs to refresh after each page is loaded.

```
    <?php
function real_date_diff($date1, $date2 = NULL)  
{
    $diff = array();

    if(!$date2) {
        $cd = getdate();
        $date2 = $cd['year'].'-'.$cd['mon'].'-'.$cd['mday'].' '.$cd['hours'].':'.$cd['minutes'].':'.$cd['seconds'];
    }

    $pattern = '/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)(\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+))?/';
    preg_match($pattern, $date1, $matches);
    $d1 = array((int)$matches[1], (int)$matches[2], (int)$matches[3], (int)$matches[5], (int)$matches[6], (int)$matches[7]);
    preg_match($pattern, $date2, $matches);
    $d2 = array((int)$matches[1], (int)$matches[2], (int)$matches[3], (int)$matches[5], (int)$matches[6], (int)$matches[7]);

    for($i=0; $i<count($d2); $i++) {
        if($d2[$i]>$d1[$i]) break;
        if($d2[$i]<$d1[$i]) {
            $t = $d1;
            $d1 = $d2;
            $d2 = $t;
            break;
        }
    }

    $md1 = array(31, $d1[0]%4||(!($d1[0]%100)&&$d1[0]%400)?28:29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    $md2 = array(31, $d2[0]%4||(!($d2[0]%100)&&$d2[0]%400)?28:29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    $min_v = array(NULL, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    $max_v = array(NULL, 12, $d2[1]==1?$md2[11]:$md2[$d2[1]-2], 23, 59, 59);
    for($i=5; $i>=0; $i--) {
        if($d2[$i]<$min_v[$i]) {
            $d2[$i-1]--;
            $d2[$i]=$max_v[$i];
        }
        $diff[$i] = $d2[$i]-$d1[$i];
        if($diff[$i]<0) {
            $d2[$i-1]--;
            $i==2 ? $diff[$i] += $md1[$d1[1]-1] : $diff[$i] += $max_v[$i]-$min_v[$i]+1;
        }
    }

    return $diff;
}
?>


I'm not sure what to edit in order to make the countdown not refresh on each page load.
```

Comment: You can't use view source to see PHP code. You'll have to paste your code here.

Comment: You set `time` to contain a fixed value of `20:00:00:00`. Read the *real* time from the machine and calculate the `time left` to display instead.

Answer (score 1):

Each time I load the page the arguments to the countdown plugin are the same (see below - 20 days, 10 seconds).  You have to calculate the days/hours/minutes/seconds until your event and pass the result of this calculation as arguments to correctly initialize the countdown.  Looks like this isn't being dynamically generated at the moment - but I can't see the PHP code by looking at the source, so I can't be sure of what you're trying to do at the moment.

```
            (function($){
            soundManager.setup({
                url: 'js/swf/',
                debugMode: false
            });
            $(window).load(function(){


                    $('#countdown').countdown({
                                                    timestamp   : { 'days'      : 20,
                                        'hours'     : 0,
                                        'minutes'   : 0,
                                        'seconds'   : 10                                            },
                        duration    : 360,

                        soundURL    : 'js/flip.mp3',
                        volume: 25,
                        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

                                var message = "";

                                message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
                                message += hours + " hour" + ( hours==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
                                message += minutes + " minute" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'s' ) + " and ";
                                message += seconds + " second" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'s' ) + " <br />";

                                $('.callback').html(message);
                            }
                        })

                })
            })(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the count down timer on your page is in java-script not PHP (I have edited your question, mods will hopefully ok it).

Your java-script is setting the start of the countdown directly:

```
$('#countdown').countdown({
timestamp   : { 'days'      : 20,
'hours'     : 0,
'minutes'   : 0,
'seconds'   : 10    

...
..
.
```

What you need to do is set those values in comparison to the date the count down is counting down to! You would do this by:

1. Determining the difference from *now* until the *count-down date*
2. Working out each datepart for the count down timer (look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp))
3. Put each date part into a variable and replace the bits in the above code sample with the relevant variables.